# Speak Rate Microsoft Bing Speech API - Text to Speech

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

I have followed the sample application to generate speech from text using below GitHub repository.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/tree/master/Samples-Http/CSharp

My application is running fine only problem is speak rate or break/pause after each word.

**Input text: y u 7 f s d 2 3 e**

Following is sample SSML I am using:

`<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xml:lang="en-IN"><voice xml:lang="en-IN" name="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-IN, Ravi, Apollo)">y u 7 f s d 2 3 e</voice></speak>`

I want to pause after every alphabet. As I am using this audio to get captcha text in audio mode.

Please suggest a correct approach.

**P.S:** I don't want to repeat whole code by copy paste. (using sample from GIT)

I have even followed the conversation in comments from a link below with no luck.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/home

Comment: Have you tried "." after each word/letter?

Comment: I tried just now, "." is spelled as DOT in speech :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this -> "y". "u". "7". "f". "s". "d". "2". "3". "e". <-  it works on the bing speech web page test.
It should be fine for you as well.
here is the SSML:

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xml:lang="en-US">
    <voice xml:lang="en-US" name="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, ZiraRUS)">&quot;y&quot;. &quot;u&quot;. &quot;7&quot;. &quot;f&quot;. &quot;s&quot;. &quot;d&quot;. &quot;2&quot;. &quot;3&quot;. &quot;e&quot;.
    </voice>
</speak>
```

Comment: This solved the purpose. I also tried \n "newline" which is working same. Appreciate your help.